# How do I commit changes to a text file on button press?

Tags: python, application-development

I've written a small [app that creates a GUI](http://www.reddit.com/r/ubuntuappshowdown/comments/vbo7y/my_app_idea_ushare_gui/) for setting up uShare. Currently it depends heavily on the 'w' (write) and 'a' (append) functions to generate/edit ushare.conf file. But I've been trying to find a way for the app to store all the changes until a save button is pressed, and only then committing them to the actual file. I think that would be the best way of getting around having the user press enter every time they change any field (and indeed allow for GtkCheckButton).

Comment: It seems your question is more of a programming one than ubuntu related. If that is the case you should ask in stackoverflow

Comment: Your post is more appropriate at stackoverflow tagged as a GTK+ question or at the gtk forums.Since it has nothing to do with Ubuntu but the GTK+ UI toolkit itself,its offtopic.

Comment: The question is totally on topic for this site and the `application-development` tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to store configuration like this, what I recommend you do is to use the Python `ConfigParser` module. Please note you should ensure you store config files in `~/.config/<your-app-name>`. You can store config like this:

```
import ConfigParser
import xdg.BaseDirectory

# set the configdir to ~/.config/ushare
configdir = os.path.join(xdg.BaseDirectory.xdg_config_home, "ushare")

# check if the dir exists and if not, create it
if not os.path.exists(configdir):
    os.makedirs(configdir)

# create configparser object
config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
cfile = os.path.join(configdir, "ushare.conf")

# add your config items - see the ConfigParser docs for how to do this

# later in your app add this when the user presses the button to save the config:

with open(cfile, 'wb') as configfile:
    config.write(configfile)
```

Please note: I didn't actually run this code and just wrote it here, but it should work fine.

Comment: I've actually found an answer yesterday. I'm using String.IO and have a signal that dumps whatever has been written into the dummy file, onto the actual file. As for the directory, the ushare.conf file is in `/etc` and that is the target directory. But I think I might just have the app save it to the desktop, and have the user then do `sudo mv ~/Desktop/ushare.conf /etc`. Otherwise I'd just script it so it's done upon exit but after save. Thank you for your answer, though, I have another app idea where it'd come in handy!